# Alternative for add_months

Tags: sql, hadoop

I am trying to make syntax that does not use the 'add_months', due to some issues with my backend source I am using I am getting error relating to months so trying to avoid it and use something as an substitute
The syntax I currently have  I am trying to set it up to show me the first of month and last of month without using the add_month

(?Report View?='M') and ([Creation Date] between _first_of_month(_add_months(?Report Period?,-(?Look Back?)))
and _last_of_month(_add_months(?Report Period?,0)))

I was thinking maybe dateadd or something

any insight in how i should arrange this syntax to run on hadoop?

Comment: You've tagged this for Hadoop and Oracle.  Which database are you running the query against?  What error do you get with `add_months`?  `dateadd` is not a valid Oracle function but it may be valid in whatever reporting tool you're using.  Adding an interval would be valid Oracle SQL syntax but if `add_months` doesn't work it seems unlikely that `numtoyminterval` would.

Comment: The query is running against hadoop apparently. this the error I get :FAILED: Semantic Exception [Error 10011: invalid function AddMonths: <br/>org.apache.haddop.hive.

Comment: OK.  Is there an Oracle database involved anywhere?  If not, please remove the Oracle tag.

Comment: oracle is involved in some other areas in this report but i seem to be getting error when i use 'add_month' thus i am trying to find a substitute to replace 'add_month' and still show the first of month and last of month

Comment: Your example code is obviously not written in SQL. How are you actually running this code/what is it written in? Please can you provide the complete code?